# Are SQL Reporting Services Report Parameters deprecated in VS.NET 2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, reporting-services, reportviewer

We use an Reporting Services inside an ASP.NET web application. (We have an *.rdlc which is presented to the ReportViewer web control in our page). Our ASPX page wires up a few report parameters in code:

```
var parameters = new List<ReportParameter>();
parameters.Add(new ReportParameter("StoreAddress", InvoiceStoreAddress));
parameters.Add(new ReportParameter("LogoURL", InvoiceLogoURL));
parameters.Add(new ReportParameter("StoreName", InvoiceStoreName));
ReportViewer1.LocalReport.SetParameters(parameters);
```

These are just general parameters that are passed to the report, instead of hooking it up to a data source.

Recently, we upgraded to VS.NET 2010. We upgraded the *.rdlc to the newest version and also upgraded the ReportViewer control used by ASP.NET. Everything works as it did before.

However, I now want to add a new report parameter to my *.rdlc. I typically right-clicked on the top left corner and clicked on "Report Parameters" to add it. With the new VS.NET, I cannot find this option anywhere - it is not even in the report properties.

Where did it go? Are they deprecating this feature? How should I be passing some general parameters now?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the "View->Report Data" menu opens a tool window that contains the report parameters.